# Lack of nonpublic project description option

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page

The [Stack Overflow Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com) profile allows to user to specify the executed projects and that's great, but the problem is that in order to add a project description you have to provide a link to the project (e.g. `github`, `sourceforge`, `app store`, etc.) and it's not always possible since far not all projects are public and available online. A great example of such kind of projects is a final project at a university during the B.Sc. or M.Sc. degrees.

This is especially important for the fresh alumni, for them the degree final project is a significant if not the only part of the professional experience.

In contrast, in Linkedin there is such option where a person can describe the projects, where he participated, even if such projects are currently not available online.

Comment: You have not requested any feature. Are you asking for Stack Exchange to provide a place to upload projects, or remove the need to link to them? Also, what is the problem with uploading your project to somewhere like github?

Comment: @James OP would like to add/describe his university degree final projects that are non-public i.e. not hosted on the web-based repository hosting service provider like GitHub. This feature is not available on SO Careers. Please see my answer.

Comment: +1 Excellent suggestion. I really hope that you get [status-planned] for this feature-request. Fingers crossed!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP's: (emphasis is mine)

Post title:

> Lack of **nonpublic project** description option
>
> This is especially important for the **fresh alumni**, for them the **degree
>   final project**

and

> In Linkedin there is such **option where a person can describe the
>   projects,** where he participated, even if such projects are currently
>   not available online.

I can sense that OP wants to have an option in Stack Overflow Careers profile where he can enter/describe his class projects completed in the final years of degree levels e.g. Bachelor of Science (B.Sc.) and Master of Science (M.Sc.). These projects are mostly in-lab projects (private) at the University. Some universities do not allow their students to upload the class projects on the popular web based repository hosting service like Github.

Currently, Stack Overflow Careers profile allows you to add public open source projects hosted on the sites like GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, Google Code, CodePlex, SourceForge, etc. There is also an option to enter the URL of the project home page if the project host is not from these sites. Basically, you must have a website or web-based repository hosting service provider in order to link your project. And this is where OP is currently facing a problem.

As per the blog posted on July 15, 2011, LinkedIn introduced a "**[New Profile Sections Designed for Students](http://blog.linkedin.com/2011/07/15/student-profile-sections/)**". Here are some relevant  excerpts from it:

> 1. Students are different from typical LinkedIn professionals – with less
>      work experience to add to their profiles.
> 2. But what about students just starting out who may not have extensive
>      work history?  To help students showcase the skills and experience
>      they’ve achieved during their school years, we’re pleased to announce
>      the launch of new LinkedIn profile sections.
> 3. **Projects**: Participating in projects shows that you can apply classroom learning to real-world challenges and work effectively in a
>      team. Add compelling research or class projects to your profile –
>      especially those that demonstrate experience relevant to your
>      professional goals.

I second the feature request for having an option to describe your class projects that will give fresh alumni an opportunity to show potential employers that they do more than study on campus.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. P.S. what stands for `OP` acronym?

Comment: @MikeB. Original Poster, usually... see also [in the glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420/222299)

Comment: @MikeB. I'm glad to help but you have raised a very important issue here. My wife will be finishing her Computer Graphics/Visual Communication degree soon and she has done couple of excellent classroom projects that are worth mentioning. See even LinkedIn made a provision for this 4 years back. SO Careers profile should give an option for the same. Let's wait n see what Careers team says.